# Timestamp with timezone in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I am currently searching my transaction table using the following query. The second TO_TIMESTAMP is specified as 2019-08-21..

```
SELECT t.* FROM Transaction t WHERE t.datetime >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01T07:54:34','YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MI:SS')
AND t.datetime < TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-08-21T14:38:34','YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MI:SS') AND (t.location_1 = 2001 OR t.location_2 = 2001);
```

It returns me the following result:

[image]

When i change the second TO_TIMESTAMP to 2019-08-22.. It returns me the current day's result. I am not sure why I need to add one more day in order to retrieve the current day's result..

[image]

The current timezone in the PostgreSQL 9.6 is:

[image]

Comment: What time zone is the server in? (Do `SHOW TIMEZONE;)`

Comment: ... and in which time zone to you want `2019-08-21T14:38:34` to be?

Comment: It is currently in Etc/UTC.. For 2019-08-21T14:38:34, I just want to be able to search as it is in the search query result table.

Comment: You don't need the `TO_TIMESTAMP` when using the ISO8601 format with Postgresql. It works naturally as `t.datetime < '2019-08-21T14:38:34'`

Comment: ETC isn't a time zone I recognize; what is its full name?

Comment: *why I need to add one more day in order to retrieve the current day's result* did you state the current date for "today"? i saw you used `<` instead, which means less than the given parameter. should you use `<=` that means *less than equal to* the given parameter. cmiiw.

Comment: I'm using the TO_TIMESTAMP because I'm using Java string into the SQL query

Comment: @user990639: you shouldn't pass timestamp values as a String. Use a `PreparedStatement` and pass instances of `OffsetDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime` I don't remember which one is supported by Postgres' JDBC driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-08-21T14:38:34','YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MI:SS');

      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2019-08-21 00:38:34+00
(1 row)
```

The unescaped `T` confuses the parser (the actual result may even be buggy).

Use the correct format string:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-08-21T14:38:34','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2019-08-21 14:38:34+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you!! argh, spent half day on this problem :)